# How do I fix this guessing game of numbers 1 - 50?

Tags: python, random

The following project requires: Your program should implement a simple guessing game with the following requirements:

Generate a random number between 1 and 50 and then have the user guess the number. The program should tell the user whether they have guessed too high or too low and allow them to continue to guess until they guess the number or enter a 0 to quit.

When they guess the number it should tell them how many guesses it took.  At the end, the program should ask them if they want to play again.

For example:

Enter a guess 1-50, or 0 to quit: 25
Too high!
Enter a guess 1-50, or 0 to quit: 15
Too low!
Enter a guess 1-50, or 0 to quit: 100
Guess must be between 1 and 50!
Enter a guess 1-50, or 0 to quit: 18
That's it! You took 3 guesses to get the number.

Would you like to play again? (Y/N)

I currently have everything settled except for two issues. I cannot seem to get the play again feature to work and for some reason the first number that is guessed will not say whether it is too low or too high.

My following code:

```
import random
play = True

randomNum = 45 #random.randrange(1,50)

guesses = 1

num = int(input())
print("Enter a guess 1-50, or 0 to quit:", num) 


if num > 50 or num < 1:
        print('Guess must be between 1 and 50!')
if num == randomNum:
    print("That's it! You took", guesses, "guess to get the number.")

        #print("Guess must be between 1 and 50!")
while num != randomNum:
    guesses += 1
    num = int(input())
    print("Enter a guess 1-50, or 0 to quit:", num)
    if num == 0: 
      break
    elif num > 50 or num < 1:
        print('Guess must be between 1 and 50!')
    elif num > randomNum:
        print("Too high!")

    elif num < randomNum:
        print("Too low!")
if num == randomNum:        
    print("That's it! You took", guesses, "guesses to get the number.")

print("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)")
letter = str(input())
if letter != 'Y':
        play = False
```

I explained above what I have tried. I do believe that the issue is that the first guess does not enter the while loop. Unsure of how to fix this though.

Comment: Haha I just fixed two issues. Now I just need to figure out how to use play again.

Comment: The new code is now:

Comment: Most of your code should be inside an overall game loop `while play:` Note that you never actually *test* the boolean value `play`.

Answer (score 1):

First issue is that your while cycle only lasts until a number is guessed. So that means after you guess the first random number, your program will finish.
In order to avoid that you should declare your $play = True$ boolean on top of the cycle so you can declare your while cycle something like this:

```
    play = True
    while play:
        #  game goes here.
        print("Would you like to play again? (Y/N)")
        letter = str(input())
        if letter != 'Y':
            play = False
```

Then your cycle should continue while letter is Y or play remains True.

Second issue is that you ask for the number outside the cycle. That is not necessary, you can ask it inside after you construct your code like the example above.

I hope this clears things up.

ps. This is my first answer, so please point out if I did something wrong!

Comment: Hey! I am so sorry for the late reply, but I just wanted you to know that I really appreciate the help!! :) You did answer my question and I was able to get it to work!